# AngularJs use constant in other constant

Tags: angularjs

If I declare 1 constant like this:

```
app.constant('appHelper', {
    first: 'Firstname',
    last: 'Lastname'
});
```

and then try to use it in a second constant like this:

```
app.constant('appHelper2', {
    fullName: appHelper.first + '' + appHelper.last
});
```

doesn't work. `Error: appHelper is undefined.`

Any ideas how can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way in Angularjs to define constants with other constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494050/is-there-a-way-in-angularjs-to-define-constants-with-other-constants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
var appHelper = {
    first: 'Firstname',
    last: 'Lastname'
}

app.constant('appHelper', appHelper);
app.constant('appHelper2', {
    fullName: appHelper.first + '' + appHelper.last
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference and Credits:

[is there a way in Angularjs to define constants with other constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494050/is-there-a-way-in-angularjs-to-define-constants-with-other-constants)

http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2012/12/23/angular-better-constant-values/

Based on this, the following may be suitable for you.

```
var myApp = angular.module("exampleApp",[]);

myApp.constant('HELPER', (function() {
  // Define your variable
  var appHelper = {
    first: 'Firstname',
    last: 'Lastname'
};
  // Use the variable in your constants
  return {
    appHelper:appHelper,
    fullName: appHelper.first + '' + appHelper.last
  }
})());

myApp.controller("ExampleCtrl", function(HELPER){
  $scope.firstname = HELPER.appHelper.firstname;
  $scope.fullName = HELPER.fullName;
});
```