# Ionic configuration variables

Tags: angularjs, variables, configuration, ionic-framework

I had a look on the following official document of Ionic

```
 http://docs.ionic.io/docs/io-config
```

First it didn't work (when I run the command to add a new key it always finish with the same error "Unauthorized configuration value") and then, the document doesn't describe how to get/find the values in my angular controllers (should I use $ionicCoreSettings?).

It would be for me really useful to have a configuration file where I could put my variables, specially the url of my backend, since this one during the development period doesn't have a fixed IP.

Any idea or best practice to suggest about storing and resolving such variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question using angular constant.

To define the constant I add a look at the solution of @Linkmichiel in

[is there a way in Angularjs to define constants with other constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494050/is-there-a-way-in-angularjs-to-define-constants-with-other-constants)

and I added the use of the constant in the html with the solution of @Nimo using rootscrope in

[Can I directly access module constant from HTML under AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505138/can-i-directly-access-module-constant-from-html-under-angularjs)